# Util for a light weight web server on linux

Tags: linux, webserver

Out of curiosity rather than necessity, Is there a util on Linux to set up very light weight web server ?

Want to use it for only gets and would like a very fast install. Basically would like to programmatically start the web server.

Please let me know if the question feels incomplete and you would like more information.

Comment: how light weight?  apache/nginx are too big?

Comment: There are many, many http servers for linux. Every web framework I've used comes with a test server. There are also a lot stand alone servers that are pretty much zero-conf. Maybe, you should refine your question a little?

Comment: @nate, updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**netcat**

```
while true; do nc -l -p 80 -q 1 < somepage.html; done
```

[Source.](http://www.howtoforge.com/useful-uses-of-netcat)

Comment: on my computer (Ubuntu 10.4) nc does not allow for use of -p or -q with -l.

Answer (score 1):

you may look at SimpleHTTPServer. It is in Python, but useful enough. [Here](http://blogs.igalia.com/eocanha/?p=109) is how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

[jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) is pretty popular

Answer (score 1):

Lighttpd is a pretty awesome light-weight server for linux

http://www.lighttpd.net/

Wikipedia also has an article comparing lightweight web servers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers

Answer (score 1):

There are several light HTTP Daemons for Linux.

I would recomend:

- Lighttpd - http://www.lighttpd.net/
- NGix - http://nginx.org/

I'm sure other people have other sugestions.